# What is the risk of allowing user input in Python's 're' module

Tags: python, secure-coding, code-execution, regex

### Some context

I'm currently building an application which lets user's set up dynamic, queries they can execute later. A great addition to this seems like a regex module, in which users can filter based on a given regular expression.

This would be stored in a database and would be executed against the `re.match` function in order to limit results for the front-end, however I know certain languages (I'm looking at you, PHP) are vulnerable to code execution attacks if a pattern is passed to regular expression functions, eg:

### Example vulnerability (PHP)

```
// In this example an attacker would be able to inject `replace` with 
// the `/e` modifier and set `with` to php code to get code execution.
echo preg_replace($_GET['replace'], $_GET['with'], $string);
```

### The big question

Is this safe to (or what are the dangers of) allowing user input into Python's `re` module. Could attackers perform backend DOS attacks or even worse, execute arbitrary Python code if they are given the ability to do this?

Comment: See also [Are there any risks to matching user-supplied regex against user-supplied inputs?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112096/are-there-any-risks-to-matching-user-supplied-regex-against-user-supplied-inputs), [Is there any way to put malicious code into a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579497/is-there-any-way-to-put-malicious-code-into-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Probably, depending upon your implementation.